# Rewrite URL /blog/content/images/**/* to /content/images/**/*

Tags: nginx

My front-end is hitting `/blog/content/foo/bar.jpg` when looking for static assets.
How can I make NGINX redirect those requests to `/content/foo/bar.jpg` instead?

**At first I tried this:**

```
location ~ ^/blog/content/ {
    root /var/www/ghost/content/;
}
```

**Apparently it didn't work** – (btw, I'm testing each change in the .conf file with a `sudo nginx -s reload` + F5 in the browser.. is there a better way to test/debug NGINX behavior (and actually understand what's going on instead of this "worked / didn't work" feedback I get with each F5?)

**Then, I tried this one I found [in a cheatsheet](https://www.keycdn.com/support/nginx-location-directive) – at the `server` level:**

```
rewrite ^/blog/content/(.*)$ /$1 last;
```

Again, without luck. What bothers me is that I can't even *see* what the line above is doing and why it isn't working.

Someone, please, get me out of this "**google for a solution** -> **try something that looks promising** --> **hit F5 hoping it works (it doesn't)** -> **google for a solution**" loop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to rewrite with:

```
rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1 last;
```

But it isn't ideal. I'd prefer to rewrite *only* when the URI contains "/blog/content/"..